# Using Vector-Icons as react-native-push-notification icon

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

I'm using react-native-push-notification to show local notifications and want to show a Vector-Icon (such as Font Awesome icons) in the notification.
is there any way to use vector-icons as notification icon or it's picture or ...?
have you any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

As `react-native-push-notification` uses Android & iOS native capabilities, is unlikely you can use a fonticon as a badge with this library as it expects the usual image asset, you'd be better off using a `.png` as your icon.

If a font icon is the only way, you could try to customize the library so it can create an icon or image from a bitmap,[here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138561/draw-fontawesome-to-bitmap#40139223) of how to use a typeface on Android. Not sure if possible for iOS, but [this could](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38273654/916701) be a start to generate an asset and then use it as image.